# How to generate a YouTube playlist of the most recent videos from each channel you follow?

Tags: youtube

I follow about 20 or so channels, and while going to the subscription endpoint will show me a list of the latest videos from each channel, I still have to click each one separately. I'm looking for a way to generate a playlist of the latest uploaded videos from each of the channels I follow.

So essentially if I follow 20 channels, then this solution would generate a playlist of 20 videos, the latest one from each channel.

I know an YouTube has an API, that I'd have to learn, and then essentially code a bookmarklet in JS, but was wondering if something like this already exists?

The workflow is simple:

1. Get list of all channels followed
2. Parse list of videos by date (if no videos posted for [current] date of the request, list latest uploaded video])
3. Create playlist of parsed videos
4. Open tab with new playlist URL